# Ansible ignores remote_user switch

Tags: docker, ansible

I would like to provision a docker image using ansible. For this I have a Dockerfile like this

```
...
# import provisioning config
ADD provisioning /tmp/provisioning

# provisioning
RUN ansible-playbook -i /tmp/provisioning/inventory /tmp/provisioning/playbook.yml -c local
...
```

Since the playbook is executed during docker's image-building process it is executed as root inside the container.
Now there are tasks in the playbook which should be executed as different user (checkout a remote repo). But they are always executed as root. I've already tryied

- adding "remote_user: myuser" to the task
- executing the playbook with the option "-u myuser"

May be the connection -c local is the problem? As a workaround I could do the checkout outside the container and just add the checkout-directory to the Dockerfile, but I was wondering how to do it with ansible.

Tanks.

Comment: Have you created the user `myuser` **before** you use it in the playbook? If you don't explicitly create the user in the docker-image it won't be there (even if it exists on your host!). The basic images in docker have only some systemusers and root in `/etc/passwd`!

Comment: Yes the user is created in the Dockerfile before the ansible stuff. During my tests I logged into the container to validate that the user is present.

Comment: Are you aware of the USER instruction? Is that what you're looking for? https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user

Comment: Have you tried to build without the provisioning, login into the container and run the playbook? You can also add  `-vvvv` to the `ansible-playbook` command to get some more debug output of the run.

Comment: @SebastianStigler: the `-vvvv` revealed that the tasks were always executed with `sudo`. This was due to my global entry `sudo: yes`. Now I set this option to **no** on the tasks I needed and it works like a charme. Tanks!!

Comment: @AdrianMouat: The `USER` instruction was the final part in the puzzle. Tank you!